# poltergeist: jquery ajax does not accept one of two equals responses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

working with symfony 2.8 I'm trying to make an AJAX call to a controller that returns a JSON that contains one array.

CONTROLER:

```
public function seguimientoAction(Request $request){
    $idUnico = $request->query->get('plan-id'); 
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $idPlan =  $em->getRepository('UsuariosBundle:Plan')->findOneByIdUnico($idUnico);
    $seguimientos = $em->getRepository('UsuariosBundle:Seguimiento')->findByPlan($idPlan);


    $contenedor = array();
    foreach ($seguimientos as $seguimiento){
        $fecha = $seguimiento->getFecha();
        $fecha = $fecha->format('d-m-y');

        $peso = $seguimiento->getPeso();

        $contenedor[] = ['fecha' => $fecha, 'peso' => $peso];
    }

    return new JsonResponse($contenedor);
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var selectorSeguimiento = $(".plan-seguimiento"); 

    selectorSeguimiento.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var planid = $(this).attr("data-id");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                ContentType: 'application/json',
                url: Routing.generate('usuarios_dashboard_planes_seguimiento', {planid}),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);-------------------------------->LOG 1

                    var arrayPeso = [];
                    var arrayFecha = [];

                    for(var i in data){
                        arrayPeso.push(data[i].peso);
                        arrayFecha.push(data[i].fecha);
                    }
                    console.log(arrayPeso);------------------------>LOG 2
                    console.log(arrayFecha);----------------------------->LOG 3
                }
            });
        });
```

If I write the url that call the controller in the browser I can see this:

> [{"fecha":"26-02-18","peso":"67.0"},{"fecha":"28-02-18","peso":"66.0"},{"fecha":"03-03-18","peso":"64.0"}]

So, I understand that the problem is that javascript doesn't take the data..., but...
...If I change the array in controller and I make an identical array "artesanal way"...

CONTROLER(test):

```
public function seguimientoAction(Request $request){
    $idUnico = $request->query->get('plan-id'); 
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $idPlan = $em->getRepository('UsuariosBundle:Plan')->findOneByIdUnico($idUnico);
    $seguimientos = $em->getRepository('UsuariosBundle:Seguimiento')->findByPlan($idPlan);


    $miarray = array(
        array('fecha'=>'26-02-18', 'peso'=>'67.0'), 
        array('fecha'=>'28-02-18', 'peso'=>'66.0'),
        array('fecha'=>'03-03-18', 'peso'=>'64.0'),
    );


    return new JsonResponse($miarray);
}
```

...I receive this:

> Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
>   localhost:90:25
>
> Array(3) [ "67.0", "66.0", "64.0" ]
>   localhost:99:25
>
> Array(3) [ "26-02-18", "28-02-18", "03-03-18" ]
>   localhost:100:25

And for additional check, I turn back to call with the browser and I obtain this:

> [{"fecha":"26-02-18","peso":"67.0"},{"fecha":"28-02-18","peso":"66.0"},{"fecha":"03-03-18","peso":"64.0"}]
>
> Exactly the same that the other case

**So, the question is, Why does jquery ajax method "likes" the response with the second array and it "dislikes" the first one (being the same array)?**

EDIT: 
Here you can see a var_dump() of the arrays before the json_encode():

**Array $contenedor**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "26-02-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "67.0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "28-02-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "66.0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "03-03-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "64.0"
  }
}
```

**Array $miarray**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "26-02-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "67.0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "28-02-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "66.0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(8) "03-03-18"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(4) "64.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Javascript works well with `JSON` format. Second array is in `JSON` format and first one is not.

Comment: both are JSON, they are sended through JsonResponse() that is a method that uses json_encode() before the sending

Comment: agree the first is valid JSON.

Comment: There is something `Array(3)` at start and `localhost:*` at end of first response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass params to `Routing` as a valid javascript object, changing this line:

`Routing.generate('usuarios_dashboard_planes_seguimiento', {planid})`

by:

`Routing.generate('usuarios_dashboard_planes_seguimiento', {'plan-id': planid})`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the headers of the request. Is the content-type returned by the server, the same in both instances?

You could also try removing dataType: 'json' for a moment to let jquery "Guess"

Comment: I did that, they are exactly the same

Comment: removing dataType doesn't do anything different

Comment: Can you var_dump or error_log somewhere a var dump of the two arrays before the json encode

Comment: of course, I have edited the post at the end with both var_dump(), thanks

Comment: so clearly they are not different. I would ask you to try and put something like fiddler in place now, as we need to see the raw responses, Headers with payload.